# Parsing MySQL Data using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, mamp

Am using MAMP local host server and am trying to get the data from the table below

[image]

I don't get any syntax errors or stack errors but when a blank browser page and yes the display_errors and all are all turned On in the php.in file.

Below are the function files am using:

For the config.php file :

```
 <?php 
    define("DB_HOST", "MyLocalHost");
    define("DB_USER", "user");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "db");
    ?>
```

For DB_Connect File

```
<?php
    class DB_Connect {

        // constructor
        function __construct() {

        }

        // destructor
        function __destruct() {
            // $this->close();
        }

        // Connecting to database
        public function connect() {
            require_once 'include/Config.php';
            // connecting to mysql
            $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error());
            // selecting database
            mysqli_select_db($con,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error());

            // return database handler
            return $con;
        }

        // Closing database connection
        public function close() {
            mysql_close();
        }

    }

    ?>
```

For DB_Functions File:

```
<?php

    class DB_Functions {

        private $db;

        //put your code here
        // constructor
        function __construct() {
            require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
            // connecting to database
            $this->db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->db->connect();
        }

        // destructor
        function __destruct() {

        }



        public function getAppointments($did) {
            $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(),"SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE did='$did'");
            $appointments=array();
           if($result){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {



                $appointments[]=$row;


            }
            return $appointments; 
         }
         else{
            return false;
        }

       }

       public function getAppointmentsByJSON($did){
            echo json_encode($this->getAppointments($did));
       }


    }

    ?>
```

And for my getAppointmentsJson file :

```
<?php
//include "include/DB_Connect.php";
include "include/DB_Functions.php";

if(isset($_GET["did"])){
    if(is_numeric($_GET["did"])){
        $testObject = new DB_Functions();
        $testObject->getAppointmentsByJSON($_GET["did"]);

        echo json_encode($testObject);
    }
}

?>
```

And help advices or tips provided will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: Obviously your errors are not **on** as at least you have one syntax error.

Comment: What is it that you hope to get done? Convert the fetched data into a JSON array?

Comment: @HaiderAli Yes and print it out

Comment: @9it3e1 Have you tried the code after removing out the comma from json_encode(); Is it still the same?

Comment: @HaiderAli the common was a typo error while writing it here. There is still no changes

Comment: @9it3e1 Please switch to var_dump from echo. See what output you get.

Comment: @HaiderAli I changed the echo json_encode($testObject); to var_dump ($testObject); But still showing blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100247/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-9it3e1).

Comment: @9it3e1 Do check the answer i've posted and hopefully continue the discussion in the answer's comment section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After replicating your code and replicating the database.

The only conclusion i can come to is that, your getAppointmentsJson.php script expects a get parameter.

If you browsed to getAppointmentsJson.php?did=1 
you would see an output.

Also i edited two lines in your DB_Connect class as mysqli_error(); expects exactly 1 parameter and you didn't pass it one.

```
            $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        // selecting database
        mysqli_select_db($con,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Works Now Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to imform you but a blank PHP page is 99% of the time an error in php and usually the syntax. While you can enable error reporting in your ini file I would suggest doing that above the constant definitions in your case.

```
error_reporting(-1); // enable error reporting on known and future defined errors
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

In your `getAppointmentsJson` is an error, specifically `echo json_encode($testObject,);`

PHP expects an additional argument giving the `,`.

Comment: The comma was a typo error. It does show the error for the comma however.